Can't change checkbox unchecked color in Android Studio
I need to make a checkbox that has a dark grey border when unselected, and goes to green with the classic tick when checked
I tried a lot of different solutions I found on here, but everything I try always ends up having an ugly light grey - the default android studio color - when unchecked
I've tried to define a drawable:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_false"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_true"/>
</selector>

And passing it with:
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_layout"
//checkbox_layout is the name of the drawable xml file

I have also tried to define a style in res/themes
<style name="MyCheckboxStyle">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_dark_grey</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_green</item>
    </style>

and passing it through the style variable, but that doesnt work either.
I should also add, and this is the most infuriating thing, that it works on the android studio emulator. But it doesnt work on the phone, and I cant figure out why

Have you tried seeing how it looks like on different physical phones? Could it be an issue with that specific phone/model?

Yes I've tried, I have available a Pixel 7 and a samsung A52, and both show on screen the same thing
